# What kind of project is this? Trying to load an old VS Project in VS2012

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

This is a really old project. Pretty sure it was last worked on in Visual Studio 2003.  Im having some trouble opening from the .sln file into VS2012.  Its not loading the project and the Solution explorer just shows the Unavailable message.

I see .vb and .cs proj files and im trying to fix the .sln. So what kind of project is this?

[image]

Comment: You can open sln file in text editor (for example notepad) and see more details about projects included in solution. We don't see all files but there are minimally one vbproj (ErpReports.vbproj) file which is some visual basic project. You can try to open this project instead complete solution.

Comment: I opened the sln.  Its having trouble with "http://127.0.0.1/ErpReports/ErpReports.csproj".  I dont know if its safe to just cut this project out... Id like to somehow just set this up so the .sln will work without editing this project out.

Comment: Open `ErpReports.sln` in a text editor and post the visual studio version here.

Comment: If there's a URL in there, sounds like maybe an older-style web project. I used to have to deal with these in a previous life. You probably need a virtual directory in your local IIS called ErpReports set to the right .net version and pointing at the project folder. If it's VS2003 then you need .NET 1.1

Comment: Both projects have the same name. Is it possible that they are both implementing the same thing, just in different languages? If that's the case, they should not be both in the same solution, since they would try to compile to the same file in the bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .Sln format **version is 8.00** before the Auto one way upgrade to "Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, **Format Version 12.00**"  Doing this immediately results in a **"Migration Report"** with errors, and a project unable to load.

However, we are able to determine which project it is trying to load.  The **answer** is that this is a **C# project** and Visual Studio 2012 does not allow you to open and add multiple projects with the same name.

I tried adding the entry into IIS with no luck.  The **best solution** so far is just to open the solution, add the project and delete the unavailable project.